# edit text in android

Tags: android

hi
i want to restrict the special characters (!,@,#,$ etc.) from entering in to Edit Text field in android. how to do this please any body help..
thnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [input filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) and set it on Edit Text with [setFilters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) method

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the reference. EditTest inherits from TextView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

There you can add an TextChangedListener:
addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)

Then you test for your special characters and remove them if they are found